# PRAW Difficulty referencing Redditor and Subreddit data/instances(?) from within Submission results

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I currently have working code that scrapes subreddit's by name and pulls out the latest 1,000 submissions, inserting their data into a DB.

Now I want to do something similar, but different. I want to grab the last 1,000 submissions (posts, not comments) by a USER (if I could do this by user per subreddit, that'd be better, but I don't think the API allows it).

I have mostly accomplished this and I think I'm doing it the "right way", except for a couple pieces of data that I think I'm accessing incorrectly and though I've tried to review PRAW's docs and done due-diligence, I can't find the right way to access these things. Let me show you.

Here is my working "grab by subreddit" code:

```
    for subreddit in _PRAW_SUBREDDITS:
        for submission in reddit.subreddit(subreddit).new(limit=_PRAW_LIMIT):
            cursor.execute(
                """INSERT INTO reddit         (
                                name,
                                created_utc,
                                author,
                                link_flair_text,
                                num_comments,
                                score,
                                subreddit,
                                permalink,
                                title,
                                selftext)
                        VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                        ON CONFLICT(name)
                        DO UPDATE SET num_comments=excluded.num_comments,
                        score=excluded.score,
                        selftext=excluded.selftext
                        """,
                (
                    submission.name,
                    int(submission.created_utc),
                    str(submission.author),
                    submission.link_flair_text,
                    submission.num_comments,
                    submission.score,
                    str(submission.subreddit),
                    submission.permalink,
                    submission.title,
                    submission.selftext,
                ),
            )
```

And here is a new version of the same code that I'm trying to create a new function with that will grab "by user":

```
    for submission in reddit.redditor(_PRAW_REDDITOR).submissions.new(limit=1):
        print(
            f"{submission.name=}"
            f"{submission.created_utc=}"
            f"{submission.author=}"
            f"{submission.link_flair_text=}"
            f"{submission.num_comments=}"
            f"{submission.score=}"
            f"{submission.subreddit=}"
            f"{submission.permalink=}"
            f"{submission.title=}"
            f"{submission.selftext=}"
        )
```

Most of my results come out normal, except the reference to the user and the subreddit.

```
# This is the output to console:
 submission.author=Redditor(name='JoeBloeUsername')
 submission.link_flair_text=None
 submission.num_comments=10
 submission.score=137
submission.subreddit=Subreddit(display_name='u_JoeBlowUsername')
```

This is how I'm creating the reddit instance at the start of my code:

```
# Create Reddit instance in PRAW
reddit = praw.Reddit(
    client_id="[REDACTED]",
    client_secret="[REDACTED]",
    user_agent="Windows 10:randoapp:0.00002",
)
```

Clearly, I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to utilize the different Submission, Redditor, Comment instances  here. I thought I had a grasp on them, but then it falls apart when I try to use them, in my example.

If anyone has enough experience with PRAW to enlighten me,  you'd have my gratitude.

Answer (score 1):

`submission.author` is a Redditor object that has many attibutes.

if you wanted to store the Redditor name, you would use `submission.author.name`.

---

`submission.subreddit` is very similar,
you can use `submission.subreddit.display_name` to get the subreddit name (it starting with u_ means that it was posted to a user profile, not a subreddit)

---

The PRAW documentation is great and cover all of these attibutes with examples, I highly recommend you read it

https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/redditor.html
https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html